# Remote Content doesn't refresh

Tags: android, arraylist, android-image

I got a bit of a Problem with my App, i use a .txt File for getting the right URL's to Display my Pictures that the App should show. Everything works fine. But if i change the Content of the Remote .txt File the App keeps loading the same Pictures again. Here is the code for getting the Pics from remote.

```
private ArrayList<String> getPictures(){
    fileList.clear();
    try {
        URL url = new URL("http://server.com/test.txt");
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                url.openStream()));
        String str;
        while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
            fileList.add(str);
        }
        in.close();
    } catch (MalformedURLException te) {
        finish();
    } catch (IOException tt) {
        finish();
    }
    return fileList;
}
```

So i don't have a clue why it isn't getting the new content for i clear the ArrayList each time the method is called!

I hope someone has a Solution for this Problem, it's pretty anoying.

/edit: forgot to post the Method containing the Adapter, so here it is:

```
private String getAnImageUrl() {
    getPictures();
    ArrayAdapter<String> arrAdapt = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.main, fileList);
    arrAdapt.setNotifyOnChange(true);
    i++;
    if (i >= arrAdapt.getCount()) {
        i = 0;
    }
    return test = arrAdapt.getItem(i).toString();
}
```

Comment: I think the .txt File is cached by the Android OS in some way. Cause i killed the .txt File on the Server and ran the App again und it is still showing the Images featured in the .txt File?!?!?! That is quite confusing. Any Idea guy's?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah, I experienced this with my own app downloading some JSON. The easiest way to fix it is to add a random parameter to your URL request like so:

```
String urlString = "http://server.com/test.txt?" + System.currentTimeMillis();
URL url = new URL(urlString);
```

Which will add the current system time to your url as a parameter, which will bypass any cached version of the page